# 360 degree 3D view of a room using a single rotating kinect

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, graphics, 3d, kinect

I am working on a research project to construct the 360 degree 3D view of a room using a single rotating kinect placed in the center.

My current approach is to obtain the 3D point clouds obtained by kinect after every 2 to 5 degrees of rotation, using  the Iterative Closest Point Algorithm.

Note that we need to build the view real time as the kinect rotates so we need to capture the point cloud after a small degree of rotation of kinect.

However the ICP algo is computationally expensive.

I am looking for a better solution to the above problem. Any help/ pointers in this direction will be appreciated.

Comment: Define "better". Faster at the cost of less precision?

Comment: No... Not faster at rhe cost of precision... Something which is fats and precise....

Comment: Your best bet may be the Kinect Fusion algorithm. Google it. IIRC, the authors implemented it on a GPU, but you may be able to trade off updates/sec for a fewer number of (CPU) cores.

Comment: Just to add to Rahul's comment, have a look at [PCL](http://pointclouds.org) which has a Kinect Fusion like application included, amongst many other point cloud features.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how familiar you are with the intersection of machine learning and computer vision. But recently, a much harder problem has been solved with advances in machine learning: generating 3D models of large areas from an unstructured collection of images. For example, this example of **"building Rome in a day"**: [see this video, as it may just blow your mind](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qYaU1GeEiR8).

With your mind suitably blown, you may want to check out the machine learning techniques that allowed this computation to take place efficiently [in this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=psmCICcM-b4).

You may want to follow up with [Noah Snavely's PhD thesis](http://grail.cs.washington.edu/theses/SnavelyPhd.pdf) and check out the algorithms that he used and other work that has been incorporated to build this system. It seems that the problem of reconstructing a single room from one rotating point must be a much easier inference problem. Then again, you may just want to check out the implementation in [**their software**](http://phototour.cs.washington.edu/bundler/) :)

Comment: Downvote for recommending an offline algorithm as a solution to a real-time problem (explicitly asked by the user).

Comment: I'm mainly suggesting some pointers to machine learning and inference techniques. Try not be so closed-minded to think that if you can't use the software as-is, then it's useless. If it runs fast enough to reconstruct thousands of images into an entire city, it's may well be fast enough to produce the structure of a single room in real time.

Comment: [Removing downvote, since you seem to want to introduce people to the wonderful world of Bundler (even if they don't really need it)] While the methods you suggest work, they take several minutes to process several thousand *images* into *point clouds*. What OP has is a Kinect and therefore, he is not starting from images. Rather, he has RGB+Depth as input. You suggested that he (a) discard the depth and (b) apply an offline algorithm to solve his problem. How was this a useful reply?